# I want to add the cell values of an entire row in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

But the problem is that new columns are always added

Suppose at the present moment I have the last column named 'w'.

```
=sum(a1:w1)
```

will Do the job of adding all the cell values in first row

What can I do if new column is added? I don't want to keep editing  =sum() manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either add new column before W column and then move it behind W column or you can do some advanced sum:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, 1)&":"&ADDRESS(1, COLUMNS(1:1))))
```

or shorter:

```
=SUM(A1:1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just sum all the cells in the row:

```
=SUM(1:1)
```